# Implement a @blur in v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to implement a method on blur in v-select field but I am able to figureout how. I could easily it on a v-text-field but please help me figureout to implement it on v-select.

This is how I did on v-text-field and it worked and I was trying the same way on v-select but it is not working.

```
<v-text-field
 v-model='agent.name'
 @blur="getUp">
</v-text-field>


<v-select
  attach
  :items="areas"
  v-model="agent.areas"
  @blur="getUp">
</v-select>
```

Comment: It works just fine - https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-brook-ggkq0?file=/src/App.vue